# Use flash vectors for ESP32 / ESP8266 EEPROM

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, esp32

I recently bought an ESP32-WROOM-32 and struggle storing data permanently on more than one sector of the flash. I know, that the ESP32 has a flash ~4MB and can access it using the EEPROM.h library.

I wrote the following code as a PoC:

```
#include "EEPROM.h"

EEPROMClass epr = EEPROMClass(0);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  epr.begin(6);
  byte t = epr.read(5);
  Serial.print("read: ");
  Serial.println(t);
  epr.end();
  epr = EEPROMClass(1);
  epr.begin(6);
  t = epr.read(5);
  Serial.print("read: ");
  Serial.println(t);
  epr.end();
  
}

void loop() {
  
  epr = EEPROMClass(0);
  epr.begin(6);
  byte t = epr.read(5);
  epr.write(5, t+1);
  epr.commit();
  epr.end();
  epr = EEPROMClass(1);
  epr.begin(6);
  t = epr.read(5);
  epr.write(5, t+10);
  epr.commit();
  epr.end();

  delay(100);

}
```

My Idea was, by calling EEPROMClass(sector) to write in different locations. But on startup I get the same values for both sectors.

Can someone tell me what I am missing please?

Cheers

PS: I Know there is the SPIFFS library, but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The `vector` argument that you pass to the `EEPROMClass()` constructor is ignored on the ESP32.

On the ESP32, the `EEPROM` library is implemented by storing values in a blob that's stored in flash using the ESP-IDF's `nvs` (non-volatile storage) library. `nvs` is a simple key/value store kept in a dedicated part of the ESP32's flash storage. The `EEPROM` library uses only one blob and simply ignores the `sector` argument passed to its constructor.

You can confirm this by looking at [the source code for the `EEPROM` library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/src/EEPROM.cpp#L42):

```
EEPROMClass::EEPROMClass(uint32_t sector)
// Only for compatiility, no sectors in nvs!
 : _handle(0)
  , _data(0)
  , _size(0)
  , _dirty(false)
  , _name("eeprom")
  , _user_defined_size(0)
{
}
```

As you can see, the `sector` argument is never used.

The `EEPROM` library's [`README`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/README.md) makes it clear that the library is deprecated and recommends using the [`Preferences`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/Preferences) library instead. However, the `Preferences` library won't provide multiple namespaces that you seem to be looking for from the `EEPROM` library.